# How to connect Azure Storage to read .txt files from blob storage

Tags: windows, azure, cloud

Could anyone let me know how to read a text file from Azure Blob Storage?

Answer (score 15):

It's pretty easy:

```
string text = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("<your connection string>").CreateCloudBlobClient().GetBlobReference("path/to/the/blob.txt").DownloadText();
```

Of course, if the blob is in a public container, you can just do:

```
string text = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://youraccount.blob.core.windows.net/path/to/blob.txt");
```

Comment: I do not have access to `GetBlobReference("String")` instead I have `GetBlobReferenceFromServer()` am I forgetting something?

Comment: This answer is from 2010. It wouldn't surprised me if the method names have changed in the intervening years.

Answer (score 2):

```
// connect to development storage. To connect to azure storage use connection string
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
CloudBlobClient client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

// if you know the blob you want to access you can do this:
CloudBlob blob = client.GetBlobReference("containername/blobname.txt");

// To display text in console:
Console.WriteLine(blob.DownloadText());
Console.ReadKey();
```