# Accessing Azure Blob Storage from a VB6 App

Tags: vb6, azure-blob-storage

Does anyone know if its possible to connect to Azure blob storage from a VB6 App and, if so, how would you do it?

I've got a CMS written in VB6 and I need to offer uploading images and files to the web server. The idea is that we'll store images and files in Azure blob storage but seeing how I'm not using the .Net framework how could I do it? If at all.

Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be completely off, but I think the easiest way to access Azure is from a web service that is actually running on Azure.  So I would write a web service that's sitting on Azure and then hit the web service from VB6.

There are a number of libraries out there that allow you to access Web Services from VB6.

Comment: Would I be able to upload files and view files from within the blob storage via a webservice though?

Comment: @Steve, I don't see why not.  You could use this one as your starting point: http://weblogs.asp.net/cfranklin/archive/2006/01/29/436838.aspx

Answer (score 2):

A VB6 CMS that uses Azure? +1, Rock and roll!

I think I would write a .Net component to [access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151626/how-to-connect-azure-storage-to-read-txt-files-from-blob-storage/4152363#4152363) the Blob storage, [make it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346620/making-a-dll-com-accessible) COM-visible, and call it from VB6 via COM.

Comment: Yeah I like that idea. I think thats worth playing around with - Thanks MarkJ

Comment: Then you could use Azure SDK. It handles authentication and upload very well.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use a simple PUT via WinHTTPRequest, etc?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179451.aspx

Comment: Thanks Bob - I'll have a play around with this.